# Clarification of some known issues in monocular visual odometry

Tags: computer-vision, stereo-vision, multi-scale-analysis

so I'm reading an academic paper about some state of art algorithm of VO using deep learning, and there are some "known" issues of classical computer vision approaches that the authors bring up which I less known with. I will be glad for some clarification and reading references.

The paper is: [TartanVO](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2011.00359.pdf)

I bring here a few quotes from the paper:

> From the theory of multi-view geometry, we know that recovering the
> camera pose from a sequence of monocular images has scale ambiguity.
> Besides, recovering the pose needs to take account of the camera
> intrinsic parameters (referred to as the intrinsics ambiguity later)

another one:

> The motion scale is unobservable from a monocular image sequence. In
> geometry-based methods, the scale is usually recovered from other
> sources of information ranging from known object size or camera height
> to extra sensors such as IMU

For my understanding, here are brought up at least 3 different scales issues and I'm a little bit confused from that diversity of scale issues.

Is the scale ambiguity is the issue in simple words of determining whether, for example if we see a an object which covers a big part of the image, is small and close or big and more far ?
Isn't that caused by the following unknown intrinsics, which is addresses the intrinsics ambiguity ?
Isn't that tightly defined ambiguities if not the same ?

Isn't the motion ambiguity also resolves if the scale ambiguity is solved?

Let's compare this with binocular vision. If the the vision is binocular (2 camera eyes) we can firstly calibrate the cameras and in that that way to solve intrisics ambiguity and also the scale ambiguity as we can compute disparities of objects and their approximated depth, which also resolves the motion ambiguity as if we know the depth we know the motion.

Maybe I mixed it up because I don't understand the gentle differences between the different ambiguities.

Can you give 3 examples, each one emphasize the different ambiguity for scale, intrinsics and motion  (or less if one of them is actually some expansion of another)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one "ambiguity": world scale is unknown. As you note, given a monocular image sequence observed from a calibrated camera (that is, with known intrinsic parameters), it is impossible a priori to tell if you are looking at large objects far away while doing long jumps between frames, or at small objects nearby while taking short steps.

Incidentally, this ambiguity is what makes "[miniature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miniature_effect)" movie visual effects possible.

The ambiguity is resolved by providing a reference, either in the form of an object of known shape and size ("calibration rig") observed in the scene, or with instruments yielding the physical motion (e.g. a GPS device on the camera).

Comment: Reminds me of [this Father Ted skit](https://youtu.be/MMiKyfd6hA0).

Comment: Or, as mentioned, use an IMU.  You won't have any useful information about scale until you see an acceleration -- but at that point the visual processing will tell you an acceleration times scale, and the IMU will tell you the _actual_ acceleration.  From that, a Kalman filter or whatever would determine the scale factor for you.